# Installing rsymphony package for r (non-zero exit status)

Tags: r, package

I am trying to install Rsymphony to be able to install fPortfolio.
I get an error when I try to install it;

> install.packages("Rsymphony")
>   Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Olve/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>   Package which is only available in source form, and
>     may need compilation of C/C++/Fortran: ‘Rsymphony’
>   Do you want to attempt to install these from sources?
>   y/n: y
>   installing the source package ‘Rsymphony’

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/Rsymphony_0.1-22.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 7447 bytes
downloaded 7447 bytes

- installing *source* package 'Rsymphony' ...
  ** package 'Rsymphony' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
  Warning: running command 'sh ./configure.win' had status 127
  ERROR: configuration failed for package 'Rsymphony'
- removing 'C:/Users/Olve/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/Rsymphony'
- restoring previous 'C:/Users/Olve/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/Rsymphony'
  Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.0/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Olve\Documents\R\win-library\3.3" C:\Users\Olve\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpUjRTsG/downloaded_packages/Rsymphony_0.1-22.tar.gz' had status 1
  Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘Rsymphony’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\Olve\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpUjRTsG\downloaded_packages’

I use RStudio with R 3.3 and Windows 7 64bit, most of the other posts I have seen related to this is from OSX users getting slightly different error messages, and none of their solutions have helped me (downloading and installing symphony, not sure if i have done this correctly either)

Edit: Stedy's solution worked, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since its a Windows 7 machine, you will want to use the zip file instead of the tar file:

```
> install.packages('Rsymphony')
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/zstednic/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of
  C/C++/Fortran: ‘Rsymphony’
  These will not be installed
> install.packages('Rsymphony_0.1-22.zip', repos=NULL)
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/zstednic/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
package ‘Rsymphony’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> library(Rsymphony)
>
```